# Why is the Fourier series of a continuously differentiable function absolutely convergent?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Let $f$ be a $2\pi$-periodic continuously differentiable function. Let $\hat{f}(n)$ denote the $n$-th Fourier coefficient of $f$. How would I prove that $$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \left | \hat{f}(n) \right |$$ converges?

I have looked on StackExchange for the same question, but I all could find were half-solutions. From what I can tell, I have to use Parseval's identity and the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality on $f'$, but it is unclear to me how/where to use the C-S inequality.

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could provide a step-by-step solution.

Comment: Perhaps you could look at $\hat{(f')}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can show that $\hat{f_k'} = i k \hat{f_k}$ and $\sum_k |\hat{f_k'}|^2 < \infty $.

Cauchy Schwartz gives:

$\sum_k |\hat{f_k}| = |f_0| + \sum_{k \neq 0} |\hat{f_k}| \le |f_0| + \sum_{k \neq 0} {1 \over |k|}|k\hat{f_k}| \le |f_0|+\sqrt{\sum_{k \neq 0} {1 \over k^2} } \sqrt{ \sum_k |\hat{f_k'}|^2 }$.

Comment: The one thing I don't understand about this, is how to show that $\sum_k |\hat{f_k'}|^2 < \infty$. Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: Since $f'$ is continuous is it is square integrable and the Parseval shows that the Fourier series of $f'$ is square summable.

Comment: Ah right, I see. But then why is the inequality $\sum_{k \neq 0} |\hat{f_k}| \leqslant \sum_{k \neq 0} \frac{1}{k} |k \hat{f_k}|$ true? If I just plug in any sequence, it tends to be the other way around. For example, $\sum_{k \neq 0} \left | \frac{1}{k^2} \right | = \frac{\pi^2}{3} \nleqslant \sum_{k \neq 0} \frac{1}{k} \left | k \frac{1}{k^2} \right | = 0$.

Comment: I was missing absolute value on the $k$!

Comment: I've been thinking about this for a long time, but I believe your answer still contains an error. It's in what you believe to be the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality; the final step. Take the sequence $a_n=2^{-|n|-2}$. Then $\sum_n |a_n| = \frac{3}{4} \nleqslant a_0 + \left ( \sum_{n \neq 0} n^{-2} \right ) \left ( \sum_{n \neq 0} |a_n|^2 \right ) \approx 0.387$.

Comment: It is missing a square root. I am sure you are aware of that. I will fix it later.

Comment: If I might make a suggestion; I think it better to first focus on the general idea rather than the detail. Every paper & book will have minor omissions and you need to develop the skills to follow the intent where the execution has been flawed. In the above I had two minor omissions but the intent is not too hard to discern. For example, multiplying and dividing by $k$ or the omission of the square root in the application of Cauchy Schwartz. I try not to make mistakes, but they are inevitable.

Comment: Alright, it finally makes sense to me now. I get where you're coming from, saying I should look at the big picture. Still, I believe it is important - especially in maths - to be precise. Small errors may cascade and lead to large errors in the end (not the case here, but I think you understand what I mean). Personally I always look through formulae and proofs very thoroughly, convincing myself step-by-step why they are true. If one step does not seem intuitive (possibly because it is erroneous), my entire intuitive understanding of the piece falls apart.

Comment: I understand & agree. Unfortunately it is an enormous amount of work to be completely correct, even on small things such as above.